# Free-forgetful adjunction for modules over monoids in the enriched functor category $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$.

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{V},\otimes,I)$ be as closed, symmetric monoidal, bicomplete category and $\mathcal{C}$ a skeletally small $\mathcal{V}$-category. Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ itself has a monoidal structure $\oplus:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ with unit $\emptyset$.

Then the category $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched functors $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}$ is itself naturally enriched over $\mathcal{V}$, with hom-objects defined by the enriched ends

$$\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}(X,Y)=\int_{c\in\mathcal{C}}\mathcal{V}(X_c,Y_c),\qquad X,Y\in\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}.$$

Furthermore, this functor category carries a monoidal structure given by Day convolution. In detail, for $X,Y\in\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$ we define their product $X\widehat\otimes Y$ as the enriched left Kan extension of $X_-\otimes Y_-:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}$ along $\oplus:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$. To be concrete we can understand it by the coend formula
$$(X\widehat\otimes Y)_c=\int^{d,e}\mathcal{C}(d\oplus e,c)\otimes X_d\otimes Y_e.$$
It is an easy application of the $\mathcal{V}$-Yoneda Lemma that the unit for this product is the corepresented $\mathcal{V}$-functor $\mathcal{C}(\emptyset,-)$.

Now by a *monoid* in $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$ we understand a monoid for the convolution product. Specifically one such is a $\mathcal{V}$-functor $R$ together with $\mathcal{V}$-enriched product $\mu:R\widehat\otimes R\Rightarrow R$ and unit $\eta:\mathcal{C}(\emptyset,-)\Rightarrow R$ natural transormations  that make the expected diagrams commute. By a *module* $M$ for a monoid $R$ we again mean with respect to the convolution product. That is, a $\mathcal{V}$-functor $M$ together with a $\mathcal{V}$-natural transformation $\rho:M\widehat\otimes R\Rightarrow M$ that makes the obvious associativity and unit diagrams commute.

Now if $M,N$ are $R$-modules in $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$, then we can define a map of $R$-modules between them to be a $\mathcal{V}$-natural transformation $f:M\Rightarrow N$ which makes the obvious diagrams commute. In this way we get a subcategory $R\mbox-mod_\mathcal{C}$ of $R$-modules in $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$, which we can enrich with hom-objects defined by means of equalisers
$$R\mbox-mod_\mathcal{C}(M,N)\dashrightarrow\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}(M,N)\rightrightarrows\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}(M\widehat\otimes R,N)$$
where the top arrow is $\rho_M^*$ and the bottom arrow is $\rho_{N*}(-\widehat\otimes R)$.

Now, onwards to the actual question. Let $X\in\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$ be any functor and $R$ a monoid in $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$. Then $X\widehat\otimes R$ is the 'free' module on $X$, and for any $R$-module $M$ we expect a free-forgetful natural isomorphism
$$R\mbox-mod_\mathcal{C}(X\widehat\otimes R,M)\cong\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}(X,M).\qquad (\ast)$$
This is exactly what happens in the classical case, in which the theory reduces to that of rings and modules. However, I could not myself work through the details, although they are probably/hopefully not too complicated.

> Can someone fill in the details for why the previous adjunction $(\ast)$ should/should not hold?

Also, if I have made any mistakes above recalling the details, please do point it out.

Comment: If this is to work (and following the intuition of why it's usually true) : You want a map $\mathcal V^\mathcal C(X,M)\to R-mod_\mathcal C(X\hat\otimes R, M)$. The RHS is an equalizer, so you want a map to $V^\mathcal C(X\hat\otimes R,M)$ making the appropriate diagram commute.This map is clear : it's $\rho_{M*}\circ (-\hat\otimes R)$, the fact that the appropriate diagram commutes should just be some formal game . (1/2)

Comment: The map in the other direction should be a restriction to $R-mod_\mathcal C(X\hat\otimes R, M)$ of $\mathcal V^\mathcal C (X\hat \otimes R , M)\to \mathcal V^\mathcal C(X,M) $ which is defined by pullback of $X\to X\hat\otimes \mathcal C(\emptyset, -) \to X\hat\otimes R$. With a bit of luck, drawing all the appropriate diagrams shows that these are inverse maps in $\mathcal V$  (I probably didn't bring you anything new, but this is just in case you were wondering how to define the maps)(2/2)

Comment: Did I miss something. Why not prove this for an arbitrary $\mathcal{V}$ category with monoidal structure satisfying suitable conditions and then apply the result to $\mathcal{V}^{\mathcal{C}}$? I suppose that by $M\wedge N$ in (*) you mean $M\hat \otimes N$? Also $X\hat \otimes R$ should be the 'free' module on $X$ not monoid.

Comment: @Nex, thanks for the corrections. Your suggestion of a more general approach seems worthwhile, but really the case described is what I was hoping to understand. If you have something to post that woudn't be too difficult for me to put into the present context I'd be interested in redressing my question a little and reading it.

Comment: @Max, thank you! I have to admit that I hadn't noticed the first map for some reason! I was struggling to find an inverse for the second, mapping out of the equaliser. I think that's exactly what I need!

Comment: @Tyrone : you're welcome, hopefully it will work. Although at first sight I would agree with Nex, that this should work more generally in any $\mathcal V$-enriched monoidal category, perhaps with some added hypotheses (if one can give some meaning to "$\mathcal V$-enriched monoidal category", I'm not entirely sure). I'll try to work it out if I have the time.

Comment: (from what I can tell it will work in the more general context, the diagrams one has to write just very quickly get big so I'll need bigger sheets of paper to check it and write down a full-proof. Maybe a Yoneda proof would be quicker)

Comment: I hope I'm not bothering you, but I am now not far from convinced that the quickest way to get there is to prove the result for non-enriched free modules, and then use a Yoneda-type argument to get the result for enriched categories that are tensored over $\mathcal V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rotimes}{\hat\otimes}$
Here's a sketch of a proof, I suspect it should be enough :

Step 1 : Prove the result in an un-enriched case, that is : if $(\mathcal V, \otimes, I)$ is a monoidal category, $R$ a monoid-object in $\mathcal V$, then $X\mapsto X\otimes R$ is left-adjoint to the forgetful functor $(R-mod)^0 \to \mathcal V$ (where $(R-mod)^0$ is the unenriched category of $R$-modules). This involves some reasonable diagram-chasing, if you want more details I can add them but it's not too hard : define the obvious adjunction maps and draw the correct diagrams to see that they are inverse.

Step 2: Use the Yoneda lemma. More precisely, let $(\mathcal V,\otimes, I)$ be a closed symmetric bicomplete monoidal category, $(\mathcal M, \rotimes, e)$ a $\mathcal V$-enriched monoidal category ($\rotimes$ is an enriched bifunctor - though to be fair I'm not sure it needs to be enriched) which is tensored over $\mathcal V$, with tensor $\odot$.

I'll use the following notations : $\hom$ is the hom-*set* in $\mathcal V$ and in $\mathcal M$, $\newcommand{\rhom}{\mathcal{Hom}}$ $\rhom$ is the hom-$\mathcal{V}$-object in $\mathcal M$ (note that we have, by definition of hom-set for an enriched category : $\hom(X,Y) = \hom(I, \rhom(M,N))$ for $M,N\in \mathcal M$). Then the tensoring $\odot$ should satisfy $\hom(Y, \rhom(M,N)) \cong \hom(Y\odot M,N)$ (you can probably even ask for an enriched adjunction here, but it's not necessary, so I'm not getting into that)

Tensoring should also be compatible with $\rotimes$ in the sense that $Y\odot (M\rotimes N) \cong (Y\odot M)\rotimes N$ and this isomorphism should be compatible with all the data in $\mathcal M$: associator, unitor.

With all this under the belt we can see :

For any monoid-object $R$ in $\mathcal M$ and any $R$-module $M$, $Y\odot M$ is canonically an $R$-module with the obvious structure maps. Then we have the following string of isomorphisms $$\hom(Y, \rhom(X,M)) \cong \hom(Y\odot X, M) \cong \hom_{(R-mod)^0}(Y\odot X\rotimes R, M) \cong \hom(Y, R-mod_{\mathcal M}(X\rotimes R, M))$$

where $R-mod_{\mathcal M}$ is the enriched category of $R$-modules as you have defined it (the definition makes sense for any $\mathcal M$ with the properties I gave), and where the isomorphisms are justified as follows :

the first one is just the $\odot \dashv \rhom$ adjunction; the second one is from step 1 (since we're dealing with honest modules), and the third one is to justify :

Note that a morphism $Y\to R-mod_{\mathcal M}(M,N)$ ($M,N$ arbitrary $R$-modules) is the same as a morphism $Y\to \rhom(M,N)$ equalizing the two arrows $\rhom(M,N)\rightrightarrows \rhom(M\rotimes R, N)$. By $\odot \dashv \rhom$ adjunction, this is the same as a map $Y\odot M \to N$ making the following diagram commute :

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}Y\odot M @>>> N \\
@AAA @AAA \\
Y\odot M \rotimes R @>>> N\rotimes R\end{CD}$

which is precisely a module morphism $Y\odot M\to N$; and then we apply this to $X\rotimes R$ and $M$ instead of $M,N$.

It follows (from the unenriched Yoneda lemma) that we have the desired enriched adjunction.

We then check that $\mathcal{V^C}$ satisfies the correct hypothesis, I did that bit in my head so I'm not 100% sure but it should work.

Comment: Nice! This certainly answers the question I should have posed! It's nice to see that it's a formal thing too, since I was busy playing around with the convolution product. Some comments: if for the monoidal product $\widehat\otimes$ you assume a distributive law $(x\otimes y)\odot (m\widehat\otimes n)\cong (x\odot m)\widehat\otimes (y\odot n)$ then it makes no difference whether you assume that this functor is enriched or not, since it gets an enrichment in a canonical way, basically for the same reason as you write.

Comment: And yes, $\mathcal{V}^\mathcal{C}$ is tensored and cotensored over $\mathcal{V}$, with both definitions being pointwise, and since the tensors commutes with the coend defining the convolution product, the associating assumption is met.

Comment: Ok, good to know about enriched vs unenriched product. And yes, I was pretty sure it worked for $\mathcal{V^C}$ but didn't want to bother to write it down